# nodejs server recovering from crash

Tags: node.js, microservices, fault-tolerance, resiliency

I'm attempting to build resilient and fault-tolerant services, As a test, I'm intentionally causing it to crash with an undefined variable outside the try-catch block.

I'm calling this service locally via nodejs http client, first I intentionally cause the error and then I continue to call the service.

**First time the error is** `ECONNRESET`

```
{
    "code": "ECONNRESET",
    "message": "socket hang up",
    "stack": "Error: socket hang up\n    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)\n    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
}
```

Calling the same service second-time returns `ECONNREFUSED`

```
{
    "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
    "message": "connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.4:3000",
    "stack": "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.4:3000\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)"
}
```

Microservice - Code with intentional error

```
function getEmployee() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        db.query(sql, function(error, result){
            console.log(a); // undefined var
            try {
                if(error) {
                    reject({status: 500, result: error});
                } else {
                    resolve({status: 200, result: result});
                }
            } catch(err) {
                reject({status: 500, result: err});
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Code that's calling the Microservice endpoint

```
function getEmployee() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        http.request({
            method: "GET",
            hostname: "localhost",
            port: 3000,
            path: "/employees"
        }, function(response){
            let buffers = [];
            response.on("data", buffers.push.bind(buffers));
            response.on("end", function(){
                let data = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString());
                response.statusCode == 200 ? resolve(data) : reject(data);
            });
        }).on("error", reject).end();
    });
};
```

Question is, how do I approach it that nodejs server recovers from errors and subsequent calls to this endpoint or other endpoints go through?